# Postgres interaction

Tags: c#, postgresql

I know there are many posts which asked that question, but this is kind of the problem I'm having.
There seems to be so many different ways to interface with postgres with C# I don't know which is the current recommended way, since many posts are dated and it looks like progress was made in that area.

If possible I'd like to have linq support and since this is a private project it has to be free.

Some of the possibilities I found:
Framework Entity (Npgsql)
Which does not seem to have linq support.

DBLinq which uses Linq2SQL and not Linq2Entities.
Linq2SQL seems to be deprecated.

So to ask some questions:
Is it possible (with currently available software) to set things up so I can use code like shown there?:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161164.aspx#_Toc188851309

```
using (NorthwindEntities nw = new NorthwindEntities()) 
{ 
    var customers = from c in nw.Customers where c.City == "London" select c; 
}
```

If not, what is the current recommended way to interface with Postgres?

Comment: I'd use Npgsql and NHibernate with NHibernate.Linq to be 100% honest.

Comment: Npgsql for me, only downside is that it doesn't have a CF version. And yeah if you want Linq, NHibernate.Linq works great.

Comment: Although I still haven't adopted Linq, I prefer manually doing everything :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use code like the one you showed (things like LINQ + PLINQ + EF V 1 + EF V 4 + ADO.NET etc.) and a commercial library is an option then I would recommend http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/ - not affiliated, just a happy customer...